# Why cursor doesn't reach till end of frame in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

Thanks to all,

My question looks stupid but I have problem with UITextView.

Why cursor doesn't reach to the end frame and than scroll.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the UITextView has been designed. It's basically the same logic as a typewriter. You see white space below all the time. If you want to remove that space, there's a @property that could help you remove that:

`-setContentInset:(UIEdgeInset)inset`

Remember that [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) is a subclass of UIScrollView. There's a lot of customization you can achieve by changing settings.